# Access VBA - Exporting data through Access VBA to excel. Excel is formatted. How to get filters enabled

Tags: ms-access-2010

Currently I am exporting data from Access table to excel via VBA.
Excel is protected. Some of the fields on the excel are frozen and are read only and some are editable by the end user.

I need to get filters enabled on the exported excel. How could this be done. Is there a generic piece of code, I can research based on that.

Comment: I want the end users to be able to filter the data on excel and work on it.

Comment: It was a small change that solved this for me. oSheet.Protect Password = "password123", AllowFiltering:=True. I can now protect the worksheets and still allow users to filter.